# Speeding up loc in a big dataframe with several conditions

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have a dataframe which I want to subset. I want the subset to satisfy the following conditions in the column `test`: It should not be an empty list, it should be a subset of another list and a certain name should be included in it. My code is:

```
end_df = df.loc[(df["test"].map(lambda d: len(d)) != 0)
                & (df["test"].map(lambda d: set(d)) <= set(my_list))
                & (df["test"].apply(lambda x: name in x))]
```

example: for `name = "abc"` and `my_list = ["pear", "apple", "melon", "abc"]` and the data frame

```
test                      other_1 other_2
[]                        1       2
["abc", "melon"]          3       4
["abc", "melon", "bear"]  5       6
["pear", "apple"]         7       8
```

I want my resulting subset to be

```
test              other_1    other_2
["abc", "melon"]  3          4
```

My code works, however it is slow and as it gets executed a lot, I was wondering if it was possible to speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is use list comprehension, also if need test `name` never match empty list, so `len(d)) != 0` should be omitted:

```
end_df = df[[set(d) <= set(my_list) and (name in d) for d in df["test"]]]
print (end_df)
           test  other_1  other_2
1  [abc, melon]        3        4
```